# switch condition has boolean value?

Tags: objective-c, boolean, switch-statement

This code seems perfectly logical. Why am I getting the "Switch condition has boolean value" error? I'm using it to switch the literals on a `UIButton`. It works but I still have the error.

```
bool buttonSunStatus = TRUE;

- (void) useButtonSun:(id)sender
{
    buttonSun = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    switch (buttonSunStatus) {
        case TRUE:
            [sender setTitle:@"No Sun" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            buttonSunStatus = FALSE;
            break;
        case FALSE:
            [sender setTitle:@"Sun" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            buttonSunStatus = TRUE;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's suggesting that in the case of a Boolean value an if..then..else.. may be a better solution?

Comment: Do you get the error if you use `BOOL` with `YES` and `NO` instead of `bool` with `TRUE` and `FALSE`? Of course a trivial `if/else` statement and a simple toggle of the `bool` value is much easier to read and write than using a `switch` statement in this scenario.

Comment: Changing the type to BOOL and YES/NO removes this error. Apologies - I thought I'd tried that before I posted this question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning is simply telling you that you're using `switch` statement with boolean value. For true boolean values, you should just use `if`-`else` statement, not `switch`.

Note, you will only get this warning if you use true boolean type. If you use `BOOL`, that's an `unsigned char` on Mac OS or on non-64-bit iOS. Thus you wouldn't get this warning for those targets. But if you use `bool` (or if you use `BOOL` on 64-bit iOS targets), you will receive this warning.

You can replace the `switch` statement with `if`-`else` statement to suppress this warning.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a simple if/else in this scenario, as is :

```
if (buttonstatus){
// TRUE code  
}
else{
// FALSE code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BOOL`, not `bool`.